# How to remove the selection from the country in AmMap plugin on click to the X close

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ammap

When clicking on the country some popup is opened with the corresponding country info.Within the popup i have a close X.I wanted that when clicking on Close X the selection of the country removed cause i clicked X to close it so after i again could click on that country.Now i couldnt click cause setting **allowClickOnSelectedObject** is set to false.Any idea?